# Error while creating Web service client using Spring and JAX-WS

Tags: web-services, spring, jaxb, jax-ws

while using spring and JAX-WS to create a web service client.. I am getting following error

on googling a lot about it I noticed

**This is occurring due to old version of JAXB(jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.3:compile) which is transitively fetched by maven and hence causing conflict.**

Tried fixing it using

1. By putting JAXB 2.x in jre/lib/endorsed folder .. But no help
2. Want to know if this problem can be solved by excluding the transitive dependency fetch.
3. Need to know how I can force maven to not to fetch the transitive dependency and force it to use dependency mentioned exclusively.

But my all attempts failed.. Can some one please help me with this problem

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:107)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
    at $Proxy21.isValidEmail(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.doInvoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:520)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.doInvoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:494)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.invoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:481)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy22.isValidEmail(Unknown Source)
    at com.rosettastone.succor.webservice.EmailValidateClientImpl.main(EmailValidateClientImpl.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.<clinit>(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:533)
    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 1):

This exception is most likely caused by JAX-WS and JAXB being loaded from different class loaders. These libraries were originally developed separately from the JDK, and thus had to be deployed as part of an application, but are now part of the JDK. If you continue to deploy them as part of your application, they are available in the class path twice, and interoperability problems such as that ClassCastException may result.

The easiest solution is to no longer deploy them with the application. If this is a transitive dependency managed by maven, you can do so by excluding it. In eclipse, this is a simple as:

- open your project's pom in the pom editor (which is the default editor for pom files)
- select the dependency hierarchy tab
- right-click the offending dependency
- and choose "Exclude Maven Artifact"

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the dependencies tree by running mvn dependency:tree, and then exclude the dependencies that causes you trouble.

Concerning jaxws/jaxb issue, there are many ways to specify a specific version, but we need to know what you exactly meant to do. (wsgen, wsimport, issue occured at runtime ?)

Comment: I tried doing wsimport.. but it looks like the problem which I was facing was not majorly due to difference in WSDL file I was using .. While I got error for WSDL file with spec 2.0 ... It worked fine with WSDL spec 1.1... But I am not sure about the exact reason .. hence waiting for some one to clarify here

Answer (score 0):

i hit this where jersey-json pom was pulling in an explicit version of jaxb-impl.  maven excluding that dependency did the trick for me.

more info here:

```
http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html
```

(not entirely sure why it was getting different versions of the api and impl classes, as jaxb-impl pom brings in its preferred jaxb-api, there was no funky classloading going on AFAICT, so whether it loads from JRE or from explicit jaxb JARs, it should have had compatible classes ... but it didn't, and the exclude caused it all to work!)